# Any idea why this Jquery isn't working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Edit answered below, something with document ready :)

I'm actually trying to get the contendible feature of html5 to save to ajax and then to my MYSQL table.. but for some reason I can't even get this Javascript to pop. When I look at my console I only see the 'testing console' debug. Any ideas why this isnt working for me. I've attached html and the javascript file below.

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js';
script.type = 'text/javascript';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

console.log('Testing console');

$( "#target" ).keyup(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .keyup() called." );
  console.log('Tasdasdasdasdasdasd');

});


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="new_file.js"></script>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>testing</title>
        <meta name="author" content="Gaming" />
        <!-- Date: 2014-03-06 -->
    </head>
    <body>
      <form>
        <input id="target" type="text" value="Hello there">
      </form>
      <div id="other">
         Trigger the handler
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why include jQuery twice?

Comment: There's javascript in your question... Is that javascript inside of `new_file.js`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primary cause is that you're trying to bind a handler via jQuery before jQuery even loads! Make sure your jQuery script is after your declaration, and then depending on that you may need a DOM ready handler.

You have to wait until your DOM is ready to bind handlers, wrap your jQ in a DOM ready handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#target" ).keyup(function() {
      alert( "Handler for .keyup() called." );
      console.log('Tasdasdasdasdasdasd');

    });
});
```

Or put your code at the end of the page.

Comment: He's trying to use jquery before it exists, unless i'm miss-interpreting the question.

Comment: @KevinB -- Yeah that looks like it could be an issue as well, lol, ill edit the answer.

Comment: I think he just didn't know how to separate the two code sections, in which case your answer would fix his problem. He's still including an unnecessary second copy of jquery, but it won't actually break anything i guess.